# Can I add another component inside a semantic-ui-react card without it breaking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, semantic-ui

### Background

I have an app that displays tv programs in semantic cards. There are six cards per row. I would like to add a comment container on each card. The comment container will eventually list comments specific to each program.

Since my return needs to include two JSX components, I must wrap them in a div. However, doing that messes up my formatting for six cards per row. I am unsure of a workaround, except possibly overwriting with my own CSS somehow. Google hasn't been much help, though maybe I am just not using the correct search terms.

Any ideas on what I should do?

### Code

***Programs.js***
**[Link to full file](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Programs.js)**

```
return(
      <div>
        <Grid columns='six' divided='vertically'>
            <Grid.Row >
              {props.programs && props.programs.map((program) => <Program key={program.name} program={program} />)}
            </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
    </div>
  )
```

***Program.js. I want my  to go after the*** 
**[Link to full file](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Program.js)**

```
return(

          <Grid.Column>
            <Card onClick={(_) => {}}>
              <Image src={program ? program.image : null} wrapped ui={false} />
              <Card.Content>
                <Card.Header>{program ? program.name: null}</Card.Header>
                <Card.Meta>
                  <span className='date'>{program ? program.network : null}</span>
                </Card.Meta>

              </Card.Content>
            </Card>

          </Grid.Column>

      )
```

#### Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Use a react fragment if you need to wrap two elements without a containing div: Use a Fragment: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: @azundo I always wondered about using fragments! Didn't realize it would work in this case. Thanks for helping me solve this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/) from Semantic UI React, it's fine as long as you keep everything in containers called `content` and `context extra`.

See also their example (they show code) showing "blocks of content" in https://react.semantic-ui.com/views/card/#content-content-block